# Memory Allocation in Layout

Tags: java, android, memory-management

In my project, i have a simple activity composed of a single XML layout (enabled by setContentView). The project has other activities though.

The layout is basically composed of two .jpg images. The first one has 25kB and is 400x153 px. The second one has 4kB and is 150x50 px.

Despite this very simple context, the DDMS tells me i have 13MB allocated to my program, which i think is huge, given i only have two small images loaded, and that some device have a maximum heap size of 16MB for each program.

Is it normal for the heap to be so big in this layout?

**EDIT**: HProf Dump:

> Problem Suspect 1: 
>   The class "android.content.res.Resources", loaded by "", occupies 9,429,232 (70.39%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.lang.Object[]" loaded by "".
>
> Problem Suspect 2: 
>   3 instances of "android.graphics.Bitmap", loaded by "" occupy 2,147,960 (16.03%) bytes.

```
Biggest instances:
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x41407b98 - 1,048,648 (7.83%) bytes. 
•android.graphics.Bitmap @ 0x4169e6a0 - 979,256 (7.31%) bytes.
```

I can't really interpret this. But it seems like my other resources are being loaded before-hand? (before I enter their respective activities?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say that that's all your program is trying to do, then it's normal. Bitmaps do take up a lot of memory. Try to optimize your images, and that should definitely help you in reducing the memory footprint of your apps. Think about 9-patch images while creating backgrounds.

Comment: It seems like it's indeed normal... I created a new project in Eclipse and it does occupy this same memory (in a blank activity). Thanks!